# Exponential volume control with a specified midpoint

Tags: math, volume, equation, exponential

I have a slider that returns values from 0 to 100.
I am using this to control the gain of an oscillator.

When the slider is at 0, I would like the gain to be 0.0
When the slider is at 50, I would like the gain to be 0.1
When the slider is at 100, I would like the gain to be 0.5

So I need to find an equation to get a smooth curve which passes through all of these points.

I've got the following equation which gives an exponential curve and gets the start and end points correct, but I don't know how to force the curve through the middle point. Can anyone help?

```
function logSlider(position){
    var minP = 0;
    var maxP = 100;

    var minV = Math.log(0.0001);
    var maxV = Math.log(0.5);

    var scale = (maxV - minV) / (maxP - minP);

    return Math.exp(minV + scale*(position-minP));


}
```

Comment: Does it have to be exponential, or merely smooth?  You could easily find a quadratic equation that passes through those three points.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like it to be exponential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a derivation of the function.  All it takes is some algebra.

## Model and Constraints

We want an exponential function of the following form, that takes number between 0 and 1:

f(t) = a * b<sup>t</sup> + c

The function must satisfy these constraints you gave:

f(0) = 0 = a + c
f(1/2) = 0.1 = a * b<sup>1/2</sup> + c
f(1) = 0.5 = a * b + c

## Solving for a, b, c

Let z<sup>2</sup> = b.

a + c = 0
a * z + c = 0.1
a * z * z + c = 0.5

a * z - a = 0.1
a * z * z - a = 0.5

a * z * z - a * z = 0.4

(a * z - a) * z = 0.4

0.1 * z = 0.4

z = 4

**b = 16**

a * 4 - a = 0.1

**a = 0.1 / 3**

**c = -0.1 / 3**

## Solution

**f(t) = (0.1 / 3) * (16<sup>t</sup> - 1)**

[Here's a plot.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28t%29+%3D+%280.1%2F3%29+*+%2816%5Et+-+1%29%2C+t+in+%5B0%2C1%5D)

[image: Plot]

If you want to pass in values between 0 and 100, simply divide by 100 first.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
y = 0.2*(x/100)^3 + 0.3*(x/100)^2
```

[image: graph]

The general solution for points `(50, y_1)` and `(100, y_2)` is

```
y = 2 (x/100)^3 * ( y_2-4*y_1) + (x/100)^2 * ( 8*y_1 - y_2 )
```

Comment: Note `^` is exponentiation